# Upload image from android to php server getting an error

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to upload a picture desert.png from android to a php server ,but it doesn't work for me ,and it gives me this error log :
E/Error:(1450): /desert.png: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
this is my code :

```
/**
 * Background Async Task to upload file
 * */
class UploadFileToURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Uploading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
            Log.i("lenghtOfFile",lenghtOfFile+"");
            // download the file
           InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            Log.i("InputStream","InputStream");
            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("desert.png");
            Log.i("OutputStream","OutputStream");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.desert);        
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long sentByte = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(byte_arr)) != -1) {
                 output.write(byte_arr, 0, count);
                 sentByte += count;


              //  passed=passedTime -previosTime ;
               // previosTime = passed ;

                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((sentByte*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                Log.i("log_lenghtOfFile",lenghtOfFile+"" );
                Log.i("log_total",sentByte+"" );
                Log.i("log_ourcentage",(int)((sentByte*100)/lenghtOfFile)+"" );

               // Log.i("log_Debit",passedTime +"" );
                // writing data to file
               output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
           output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }



        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
   }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded    
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

        // Displaying downloaded image into image view
        // Reading image path from sdcard
     //   String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
        // setting downloaded into image view
     //   my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
    }

}
```

Comment: check you added `READ_PERMISSION` in `manifest.xml`

Comment: I added it ,but still the same problem ,what do you think about my code ,is something wrong with it ?

Comment: post your UploadFileToUrl() code

Comment: why are you returning null from doInBackground() process??

Comment: I edited the code ,you can see UploadFileToURL code

Comment: I'm completely lost ,i don't even why i'm putting it :( sorry

Comment: Don't worry !!! follow the link that I've referred you,It works perfectly for me,hope it'll do the same for you also -@victoria

Comment: ok thank you ,i'm trying the first link , and i'm gettig this log erreor : E/uploadFile(1651): Source File not exist :/mnt/sdcard/service_lifecycle.png , how can i put a picture under  :/mnt/sdcard/ ,i'm working with emulator ?

Comment: just push a random picture from eclipse to your emulator at the same location /mnt/sdcard/service_lifecycle.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you can follow this link from [AndroidExample](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106).Another nice tutorial [here](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/09/file-upload-on-php-server-in-android.html).Don't get scared from the code,those are some conventions that you need to follow to upload image

Comment: i tried the code of the first link ,but it's always showing an error Source File not exist :/mnt/sdcard/desert.png ,I pushed the picture under /mnt/sdcard/ in the DDMS ,and restart the emulator , but still always the same message.

Comment: now you can download the complete source code from my Git repository-https://github.com/pankajgangwar/android just select the pic from gallery and upload it to your server -@victoria

Comment: the problem was solved thanks to you AndroidGeek :) but i have another problem in this link : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377470/android-4-3-httpurlconnection-no-authentication-challenges-found)

Comment: are you on g+ or skype or any other messenger?? I will solve your problem exactly the way you want -@victoria

Comment: AndroidGeek you are an android genies !!thanks it works :)))and this is my g+ : ghabriamina@gmail.com @AndroidGeek