# How to upload image to Specific URL and fetch it to imageView in android?

Tags: android, web-services, url, upload, imageview

I am developing an android application and I need to upload an Image to Following URL.

http://demo1.idevtechnolabs.com/RChatAPI/usrPhotos/

When I upload image to this URL the image should be stored in

http://demo1.idevtechnolabs.com/RChatAPI/usrPhotos/YourImage.jpg

and user can see it when he/she want from this url.

Please I have no idea what to do for this. please help me or send me any link for that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346315/upload-image-from-android-to-php-server-getting-an-error/22346860#22346860

Comment: Error in uploading the image sir

Comment: you need to configure your server also

Comment: ok can you help me how?

Answer (score 3):

Follow the given step:

1)You've to convert your image into bitmap,

2)Convert the bitmap into Base64 String,

3)Send this string to server.

To represent this image:

1) Convert this Base64 into bitmap and set this bitmap into imageview.

Follow the given link

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/464629/Pass-byte-as-parameter-to-JSON-service-from-Androi

Comment: Is there need to convert image to Bitmap format while send it to server or to specific url?

Comment: You can use other procedure such as FTP.I think this procedure is simple.

Comment: Acctully i am getting HTPP Response is: Method Not Allowed:405

Comment: Than I think http connection problem is arising or your argument is not well documented as per webservice.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (using volley to upload image)

I am only writing snippets of upload method from android side and php file to receive the file(in the form of string)

**ANDROID/JAVA code**

```
// getStringImage method will be called inside uploadImage 

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private void uploadImage(){
    //Showing the progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    //Disimissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Showing toast message of the response
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "uploaded" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //Dismissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Converting Bitmap to String
            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

            //Getting Image Name
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creating parameters
            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            //Adding parameters
            params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
            params.put(KEY_NAME, "name");

            //returning parameters
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

**PHP side img.php**

```
<?php

    $host="localhost"; //replace with database hostname 
    $username="root"; //replace with database username 
    $password=""; //replace with database password 
    $db_name="mydb"; //replace with database name

    $con=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
    $db=mysql_select_db($db_name);

    $name = $_REQUEST['name']; //image name
    $image = $_REQUEST['image']; //image in string format
    $user=$_REQUEST['User_ID'];

    $decodedImage = base64_decode($image);
    $image_file=time().rand(1111,9999);
    $name=$name.$image_file;

    $base_path='/var/www/html/uploads/';
    file_put_contents($base_path.$name.".jpg", $decodedImage);

    mysql_query("INSERT into `image`(`img`,`User_ID`,`date`) values ('".$image_file.".jpg','$user',now() )");
    echo mysql_insert_id();

?>
```

Its a late reply but I hope it helps someone else :)
If you have any trouble integrating the above code reply me .